# Propel2, createdBy field

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7, propel2

Let's say I have model "Question".
Every question is created by user (current user).
How to "auto" update `createdBy` to `current.user`

In Doctrine2 I should have event listener with dependency on `security.context`.
And event will subscribe for `preSave()`, setting `$question->setCreatedBy( $context->getToken()->getUser());`

How to achieve this with Propel2 ? I could set `createdBy` in controller, but this is ugly :(

I could write custom [behavior](http://propelorm.org/documentation/06-behaviors.html), but how to access `security.context` from the behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ~ half year I found working solution :)

Idea: Model will have setter injection for `Event Dispatcher`. On `pre-save` model will fire event (validation/user injection etc..). This way I require ED for save. I can select objects from the DB without injected ED.
Dependency manager will manage "repository". Repo will be able to inject all required dependencies on the model and then call save.
`$depepndanciesManager->getModelRepo->save($model)`.
Witch will do:

`$model->setEventDispacher($this->getEventDispacher);
$model->save();`

Example of Model:

```
class Lyric extends BaseLyric
{
    private $eventDispacher;

    public function preSave(ConnectionInterface $con = null)
    {
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // throw exception
        }

        $this->notifyPreSave($this);
        return parent::preSave($con);
    }

    private function getEventDispacher()
    {
        if ($this->eventDispacher === null) {
            throw new \Exception('eventDispacher not set');
        }
        return $this->eventDispacher;
    }
    public function setEventDispacher(EventDispacher $eventDispacher)
    {
        $this->eventDispacher = $eventDispacher;
    }
    private function notifyPreSave(Lyric $lyric)
    {
        $event = new LyricEvent($lyric);
        $this->getEventDispacher()->dispatch('tekstove.lyric.save', $event);
    }
}
```

Example of Repository:

```
class LyricRepository
{
    private $eventDispacher;

    public function __construct(EventDispacher $eventDispacher)
    {
        $this->eventDispacher = $eventDispacher;
    }

    public function save(Lyric $lyric)
    {
        $lyric->setEventDispacher($this->eventDispacher);
        $lyric->save();
    }
}
```

Example usage from controller:

```
public function postAction(Request $request)
{
    $repo = $this->get('tekstove.lyric.repository');
    $lyric = new \Tekstove\ApiBundle\Model\Lyric();
    try {
        $repo->save($lyric);
        // return ....
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Example config:

```
tekstove.lyric.repository:
    class: Tekstove\ApiBundle\Model\Lyric\LyricRepository
    arguments: ["@tekstove.event_dispacher"]
```

Config is based on [symfony framework](https://symfony.com/).
Real implementation:

- config - [enter link description here](https://github.com/Tekstove/Tekstove-api/blob/master/src/Tekstove/ApiBundle/Resources/config/services.yml)
- model - [enter link description here](https://github.com/Tekstove/Tekstove-api/blob/master/src/Tekstove/ApiBundle/Model/Lyric.php)
- controller - [enter link description here](https://github.com/Tekstove/Tekstove-api/blob/master/src/Tekstove/ApiBundle/Controller/LyricController.php)
- "Repo"'s factory [enter link description here](https://github.com/Tekstove/Tekstove-api/blob/master/src/Tekstove/ApiBundle/EventDispatcher/EventDispacherFactory.php)

*Links may not work, project is in active development!*